# Is there a substantial performance difference between using NSPredicate predicateWithBlock and using a block in a for loop?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nspredicate

Is there a substantial difference in performance (in either direction) between filtering like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id,NSDictionary*)];
NSArray *filtered = [sourceArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

versus filtering like this:

```
BOOL (^filterPredicate)(id,NSDictionary*) predicate = ^BOOL(id sourceObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {};
foreach (id sourceObject in sourceArray) {
    if (filterPredicate(sourceObject)) {
          filtered addObject:sourceObject;
    }
}
```

My gut feeling is that if there is any difference, the second way would be faster as the first has some extra baggage from the `NSPredicate` class.

If there is a difference, what is it, how big is it, and what is the source of it?

Comment: Test it and let us know

Comment: @Wain done with one property type and 1000 object

Answer (score 3):

Per @wain's recommendation I tested to find out.

I need to expand the test to get a more accurate reading, but here's my methodology and result:

- Create array of `SomeObject`
- Set `SomeObject` properties for each object
- Filter on `NSString rangeOfString`
- Compare execution times

**SomeObject.h**

```
@interface SomeObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *numericProperty;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stringProperty;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrayProperty;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *dateProperty;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *objectsToSort = [self generateArrayOfRandomSomeObject:1000];

    // Sorting with predicate

    BOOL (^predicateBlock)(id, NSDictionary *) = ^BOOL(id sourceObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        SomeObject *destinationTypeObject = (SomeObject *)sourceObject;
        if (sourceObject) {
            NSRange r = [destinationTypeObject.stringProperty rangeOfString:@"ab" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return NO;
    };

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:predicateBlock];

    NSDate *predicateMethodStart = [NSDate date];

    NSArray *filteredWithPredicate = [objectsToSort filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    NSDate *predicateMethodFinish = [NSDate date];

    NSTimeInterval predicateTime = [predicateMethodFinish timeIntervalSinceDate:predicateMethodStart];

    NSLog(@"predicateTime = %f", predicateTime);

    NSData *blockStart = [NSDate date];

    NSMutableArray *filteredWithBlock = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (id sourceObject in objectsToSort) {
        if (predicateBlock(sourceObject, nil)) {
            [filteredWithBlock addObject:sourceObject];
        }
    }

    NSDate *blockFinish = [NSDate date];

    NSTimeInterval blockTime = [blockFinish timeIntervalSinceDate:blockStart];

    NSLog(@"blockTime = %f", blockTime);

}

- (NSArray *)generateArrayOfRandomSomeObject:(NSUInteger)numberOfObjects
{
    NSMutableArray *objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberOfObjects];

    for (int count = 0; count < numberOfObjects; count++) {

        SomeObject *object = [[SomeObject alloc] init];

        int length = arc4random_uniform(10) + 4;
        unichar buf[length];

        for (int idx = 0; idx < length; idx++) {
            buf[idx] = (unichar)('a' + arc4random_uniform(26));
        }

        object.stringProperty = [NSString stringWithCharacters:buf length:length];

        u_int32_t max = ((u_int32_t)((u_int32_t)numberOfObjects * 10));
        u_int32_t randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(max);

        object.numericProperty = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:randomNumber];

        [objects addObject:object];

    }

    return objects;
}

@end
```

And the winner is... `NSPredicate` by a long shot. Why? I have no idea.

```
2015-05-13 15:17:20.708 TestingPerformance[60942:5787881] predicateTime = 0.000768
2015-05-13 15:17:20.710 TestingPerformance[60942:5787881] blockTime = 0.000923
```

**Edit 0: Mistake in original code and test with initializing appropriately-sized array**

Somehow despite my typo of `NSData *blockStart` in the original code, it still worked! I fixed it.

And I initialize the mutable array with a capacity of 1000.

New results:

```
2015-05-13 15:26:51.950 TestingPerformance[61157:5792057] predicateTime = 0.000771
2015-05-13 15:26:51.952 TestingPerformance[61157:5792057] blockTime = 0.000864
```

So the `predicateTime` is consistent and the `blockTime` improves with this small adjustment.

**Edit 1: Using traditional for loop without iterator**

```
for (int i = 0; i < objectsToSort.count; i++) {
    if (predicateBlock(objectsToSort[i], nil)) {
        [filteredWithBlock addObject:objectsToSort[i]];
    }
}

2015-05-13 15:30:25.464 TestingPerformance[61282:5793520] predicateTime = 0.000775
2015-05-13 15:30:25.467 TestingPerformance[61282:5793520] blockTime = 0.001079
```

**Edit 2: Increase N, added random array access**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSUInteger N = 100000;

    NSArray *objectsToSort = [self generateArrayOfRandomSomeObject:N];

    // Sorting with predicate

    BOOL (^predicateBlock)(id, NSDictionary *) = ^BOOL(id sourceObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        SomeObject *destinationTypeObject = (SomeObject *)sourceObject;
        if (sourceObject) {
            NSRange r = [destinationTypeObject.stringProperty rangeOfString:@"ab" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return NO;
    };

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:predicateBlock];

    NSDate *predicateMethodStart = [NSDate date];

    NSArray *filteredWithPredicate = [objectsToSort filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    NSDate *predicateMethodFinish = [NSDate date];

    [self doStuffWithArray:filteredWithPredicate];

    NSDate *predicateStuffFinish = [NSDate date];

    NSDate *blockStart = [NSDate date];

    NSMutableArray *filteredWithBlock = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:N];

    for (id sourceObject in objectsToSort) {
        if (predicateBlock(sourceObject, nil)) {
            [filteredWithBlock addObject:sourceObject];
        }
    }

    NSDate *blockFinish = [NSDate date];
    [self doStuffWithArray:filteredWithBlock];
    NSDate *blockDoStuffFinish = [NSDate date];

    NSLog(@"predicateTime = %f", [predicateMethodFinish timeIntervalSinceDate:predicateMethodStart]);
    NSLog(@"predicate time to do stuff = %f", [predicateStuffFinish timeIntervalSinceDate:predicateMethodFinish]);

    NSLog(@"blockTime = %f", [blockFinish timeIntervalSinceDate:blockStart]);
    NSLog(@"block time to do stuff = %f", [blockDoStuffFinish timeIntervalSinceDate:blockFinish]);
}
```

Here is do stuff

```
- (void)doStuffWithArray:(NSArray *)arrayOfSomeObjects {

    NSLog(@"Filtered array has %lu objects.", (unsigned long)arrayOfSomeObjects.count);

    NSUInteger numberOfSpotsToCheck = ((NSUInteger)(arrayOfSomeObjects.count / 4));
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSpotsToCheck; i++) {
        u_int32_t randomIndex = arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)arrayOfSomeObjects.count);
        SomeObject *o = (SomeObject *)[arrayOfSomeObjects objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
        NSLog(@"Object at index: %d \n  description is %@ \n stringProprerty is %@ \n numericProperty is %i",
              i,
              o,
              o.stringProperty,
              [o.numericProperty unsignedIntValue]);
    }
}
```

And still block time is a bit slower in both access and filtering.

```
2015-05-13 16:10:26.750 TestingPerformance[62201:5810268] predicateTime = 0.086866
2015-05-13 16:10:26.750 TestingPerformance[62201:5810268] predicate time to do stuff = 0.531776
2015-05-13 16:10:26.751 TestingPerformance[62201:5810268] blockTime = 0.107424
2015-05-13 16:10:26.751 TestingPerformance[62201:5810268] block time to do stuff = 0.684613
```

Comment: Try increasing your number of objects. I think you'll find that the times are almost identical, and that the noise is greater than the difference. Sometimes one is faster and sometimes the other, but they're very close for larger N.

Comment: I also find that if you optimize the code, make certain that the `filteredWithPredicate` variable is really assigned (by using it later in the code outside the timing blocks), and include the creation of the predicate inside the timing (or remove the creation of the array from the blockTime timing), that blockTime is reliably a little bit faster.

Comment: See edited code... I increased N and added a `doStuff` to randomly access array, but predicate still wins